# Swiper.js hover scroll

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to autoscroll when hovering.
An example of what I'm trying to do https://www.halo-lab.com/

The code that I use:

```
new Swiper('#swiper-corusel', {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        autoHeight: false,
        freeMode: true,
        mousewheel: {
            sensitivity: 3,
        },
        loop: false,
        roundLengths: true, 

    });
```

I'm trying to do here https://profi.ngens.ru/boris/src/index.html But so far nothing has come of it.